# What is module.globals?

Tags: javascript, module, global

Javascript modules have a `module` object which has well known property like `module.exports` which let us import functions and variables from a module.

However this object has few more properties such as `module.globals` which I couldn't find resource to explain what is it, Please help me to understand this module object.

Specifically I am curious about `globals` property, is it an alternative to global `window`? a module scope global?

```
// myModule.js
export default function test() {
  console.log("Module",module);
}
```

```
// index.ij
import test from "./myModule";
test();
```

```
// console
Module 
Object {id: "/src/myModule.js:", exports: Object, globals: undefined, hot: Object}
id: "/src/myModule.js:"
exports: Object
globals: undefined
hot: Object
accept: function accept() {}
decline: function decline() {}
dispose: function dispose() {}
data: undefined
status: function status() {}
addStatusHandler: function () {}
removeStatusHandler: function () {}
```

You can try it in [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/module-test-t4yt7?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: this is actually a "module object" generated by Webpack (?) to simulate modules in the browser... This has little to do with NodeJS modules.

Comment: Yes you right, I mixed up and confused! Thanks @JonasWilms